# warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated

Tags: c++, string

On the (C++) code below,

```
char * type = "";
switch (mix_mode) {
        case GO_HISTORY_VIDEO_MIX_VISUAL_GAS:
                type = "visual gas";
                break;
        case GO_HISTORY_VIDEO_MIX_VISUAL:
                type = "visual";
                break;
        case GO_HISTORY_VIDEO_MIX_GAS:
                type = "gas";
                break;
        case GO_HISTORY_VIDEO_MIX_LARGE_IR_DIRECT:
                type = "ir direct";
                break;
        case GO_HISTORY_VIDEO_MIX_LARGE_IR_FILTERED:
                type = "ir filtered";
                break;
}
strcpy(suffix, "avi");


snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "%s - (%s %s).%s", name_comp, type, uid, suffix);
```

I have the following compilation warnings:

```
GO_C_MSDExportManager.cpp:192:31: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
                char * type = "";
                              ^
GO_C_MSDExportManager.cpp:195:12: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
                                type = "visual gas";
                                       ^
GO_C_MSDExportManager.cpp:198:12: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
                                type = "visual";
                                       ^
GO_C_MSDExportManager.cpp:201:12: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
                                type = "gas";
                                       ^
GO_C_MSDExportManager.cpp:204:12: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
                                type = "ir direct";
                                       ^
GO_C_MSDExportManager.cpp:207:12: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
                                type = "ir filtered";
```

I see the char pointer is un-safe, but I'm not sure if something could go bad in this context, while `type` isn't used any other place.

I do have learned that the possibility to do something like  `*type = 'X';` would be bad as it would alter the string literal and possible crash my machine.

Questions:

What could go wrong with the char pointer?

Is `const char * type = new char[20];` a good fix to get rid of the warnings?

Comment: `const char* type = "";`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) 's type is `const char[]`, and note that:

> In C, string literals are of type char[], and can be assigned directly to a (non-const) char*. C++03 allowed it as well (but deprecated it, as literals are const in C++). C++11 no longer allows such assignments without a cast.

Then

> 1.What could go wrong with the char pointer?

As you said, `char *` make it possible to alter the string literal and leads to UB.

You could create an array initialized from the string literal, and then modify the array later, such as:

```
char type[] = "something"; // type will contain a copy of the string literal
```

> 2.Is const char * type = new char[20]; a good fix to get rid of the warnings?

No need to create a new array here, since you're only changing the value of the pointer itself, not the content it pointing to. You should just change the type of `type` to `const char*`,

```
const char * type = "";
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
char * type = "";
```

to:

```
const char * type = "";
^^^^^ -- !
```

This is because: `""` (the same applies to other literals) is a string literal which is of array type. In this case it is `const char[1]`.

To check it you can use compiler error trick:

```
template<typename T> struct TD;
int main() {
    TD<decltype("")> ff;   
}
```

outputs:

```
main.cpp:10:22: error: aggregate 'TD<const char (&)[1]> ff' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
     TD<decltype("")> ff;
```

where `const char [1]` is the type of `""`, its size is 1 because it keeps only null character : '\0'.

You can assign it and use as `const char*` because arrays decays to pointer to its first element.