# Is setting a const char* equal to a char[] literal safe?

Tags: c++, string

I found this in some C++ code:

```
const char *scaryPointer = "literal";
```

To my surprise, this doesn't generate a compiler warning or error (at least in Visual Studio 2008).

Is this actually safe to do? I thought that the address of the char[] literal would be invalid after that line is finished executing.

If it's safe, what happens if you reassign `scaryPointer` to a new literal? The address of the old literal gets automatically freed then? Automatic garbage collection?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595558/warning-conversion-from-string-literal-to-char-is-deprecated), but (I think) the questions/answers don't fully address my question & concerns.

Comment: Aside: the type of a string literal is `const char[N]`. The ability to assign a literal to a non-const pointer is a deprectaed backwards compatibility hack. (or has that feature been removed yet?)

Comment: @Hurkyl True, but that's not happening here.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I guess he was referring to the title missing `const`. Should it be edited?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String literals have static storage duration -- so they live as long as the program is running.  They're generally stored in the read-only program image that is loaded when the program starts.

Answer (score 2):

String literals have static storage duration, so they exist for the entire duration of program execution.

Comment: ... I don't think it was a coincidence that you worded your answer almost the exact same as the first user did.

Comment: @EvanCarslake I wouldn't plagiarize someone else's answer just to win some points. It was a coincidence.

Comment: @EvanCarslake They both used succinct English wording, choosing from the narrow vocabulary of standardese, so coincidence is quite likely.

Answer (score 2):

`const char *notScaryPointer = "literal";` is perfectly valid C. It is a pointer to a `char` in read only memory. You can later reassign it like `notScaryPointer = "some_other_literal";`. But because `const char*`s assigned to a string literal live in read-only memory, You can't change them. For example. This code snippet will probably give you a runtime error:
`const char* strPointer = "Hello, world!";
strPointer[0] = 'Y';`

If you want mutable strings, Then pointers to `char`s will not work. If that is what you want, then use arrays of `char`s.

Edit: I didn't notice what you were asking at first, But as others have pointed out, String literals have static storage duration.