# How are `#input` type macro strings allocated in C++?

Tags: c++, string, macros

This is kind of a follow-up question to one of my old questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404540/is-setting-a-const-char-equal-to-a-char-literal-safe). I found some code that goes like this:

```
#define TYPESUPPORT(T)              \
...                                 \
static const char* get_type_name()  \
{                                   \
    return #T;                      \
}                                   \
...
```

Where `T` is a variable type (e.g. `int`). `#T` is used to get the plaintext name of the macro input.

Is this safe to do? As in, how is `#T` allocated? Does it allocate a `const char*` or `const char[]` string literal, like in my first question, for each macro call or something?

Comment: Just as in the other question, all string literals are static.

Comment: The macro is irrelevant, the preprocessor converts it to a string literal and it's processed just as if you'd written `return "int";`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Why not write that as an answer, though?

Comment: Don't use macros...

Comment: @JesperJuhl when you have about 300 types you need this info (as well as 4 other functions) for, you use macros.

Comment: @JesperJuhl That is hardly a useful comment. Most metaprogramming stuff cannot be done without some macro infrastructure, for example.

Comment: @Angew To be fair, C++ provides lots of support for metaprogramming using templates and other introspection features, so there's less need for macros.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Macros are much *less* useful in C++ than in C. That doesn’t mean they are completely useless; they still are often the best tool for the job. Each new version of C++ makes that less common, but they are still necessary, and in particular they are necessary *here* without using compiler-specific functions like [`abi::__cxa_demangle`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html).

Comment: @Barmar And lots of template metagprogramming require some macros under the hood.

Comment: I think a rethink of the design might be worthwhile

Comment: @EdHeal I can't concisely explain why we did it this way, but this *is* the rethink, actually. In short, we need to be able to edit hundreds of functions with small, quick changes, and we need to be able to quickly and correctly add matching new ones. (One insidious typo in a non-macro type name would be hard to find.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Macros simply perform text-to-text translation. So after `TYPESUPPORT(int)` is expanded, the function will look like:

```
static const char* get_type_name()  
{                                   
    return "int";                      
}
```

And just as explained in the linked question, string literals have static storage duration, so there's no problem with returning this pointer. The fact that it came from expansion of `#T` is irrelevant at this phase of compilation.